# UINavigation title not showing?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

This is in my view did load. There is no title showing at all? I have a UITabBar with a UITableView and UInavigationBar inside the UITabBar.

```
//Creates navigation bar.
UINavigationBar *myNavBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
myNavBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
myNavBar.topItem.title = @"My Title";

[self.view addSubview:myNavBar];
```

Comment: Have you tried just setting myNavBar.title?

Comment: @Jordan That won't work. Just tried in Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried just `self.title = ...`?

Comment: @Undo That's right.. I gave the view controller the .title attribute and it has worked before.

Comment: ex: Search_Results_View *ydc = [[Search_Results_View alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search_Results_View" bundle:nil];
ydc.title = @"Results";

Comment: Yes, self.title changes my tababar title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myNavBar.topItem.title = @"My Title";
```

doesn't work because `topItem` is nil since there is no item. You need to add `UINavigationItem`s.

```
self.title = @"Some Title";
```

doesn't work because `UINavigationController` picks up `UIViewController`'s title and there is no `UINavigationController` here.

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"My Title"";
```

doesn't work because `navigationItem` is nil.

Solution:

Add an item (and set the title in the `UINavigationItem`) using either `-[UINavigationBar pushNavigationItem:animated:]` or `-[UINavigationBar setItems:]`

Comment: Yep. `-[UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:]`

Comment: @MarOux I was able to get the right bar button to show up, but now the title is showing on a left button instead of a title. can you help?

Comment: @Jason Try adding a flexible space element on the left side.

Comment: uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Fixed and flexible space items not allowed as individual navigation bar button item. Please use the leftBarButtonItems (that's plural) property.'

Comment: Well? Do what the guy says.

Comment: I Did, it doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"My Title"";
```

It may help you.

Comment: Why are you adding myNavBar ?. You can use default UINavigationBar. It will show title use default.